# Can we keep @Readonly in the global class after releasing package for next version

Tags: apex, global-methods

After adding @ReadOnly annotation before the global method throws the following error.

Error: Compile Error: Managed identifier can not change its ReadOnly setting at line xx column xx

Comment: are you doing a major or miner version?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `@ReadOnly` annotation changes the specification of the method, you will only be able to change the definition between major versions of your app, not patch releases.

Additionally, if your `global` method is a `Web Service` or `@RemoteAction`, etc. you will not be able to change it's definition at all, and will have to define a new method.